# What is the purpose of using a mock ajax call in testing?

Tags: javascript, testing, reactjs, tdd, nock

I'm learning about TDD React [here](http://thereignn.ghost.io/a-step-by-step-tdd-approach-on-testing-react-components-using-enzyme/) and don't understand the below test situation:

```
it('Correctly updates the state after AJAX call in `componentDidMount` was made', (done) => {
  nock('https://api.github.com')
    .get('/users')
    .reply(200, [
      { 'name': 'Reign', 'age': 26 }
    ]);
  // Overwrite, so we can correctly reason about the count number
  // Don't want shared state
  wrapper = mount(<UsersListComponent />);
  setTimeout(function() {
    expect(wrapper.state().usersList).to.be.instanceof(Array);
    expect(wrapper.state().usersList.length).to.equal(1);
    expect(wrapper.state().usersList[0].name).to.equal('Reign');
    expect(wrapper.state().usersList[0].age).to.equal(26);
    nock.cleanAll();
    done();
  }, 1500);
});
```

What is the purpose of using `nock` to fake a request? This request doesn't do anything and I'm not sure where the response goes to. I thought TDD approach is to write the test (the code starting at wrapper), see it fail, and then use a real ajax call in the actual component to test. I don't see what nock does here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the `nock` call in your code is to fake an API request. Nock captures / intercepts the call and instead of the actual response it returns a response with fake information.

The title of the test is `Correctly updates the state after AJAX call...` so the intention is to test whether the state is updated correctly, and not whether the actual API request has been successfully carried out.

This allows you to model and test different scenarios, for example, how your app behaves when receiving different datasets. It also allows you to complete your tests when the actual API may not be ready yet.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Unit Testing is to be only testing your code is the most isolated way possible. Faking an AJAX request and getting its responses is a very common practice to avoid issues with your endpoint (since this is not what you are testing anyway) and focusing on the code handling the response of this endpoint, and you can choose different models of response to test different scenarios.

Nock will simply feed the response back to your component when your call to 'https://api.github.com/users' is made